# only select one checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I would like to build a javascript so a user can choose only one option between the the mentioned below. Could you give me some pointers how to do this since I am a javascript noob.

Thank you!

This is the picture of the part of a menu 
[image]

```
<td><label for="dock_books_search_visible_online"> Visible online?</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="checkedVisibleOk" id="dock_books_visible_ok"  /> </td>
                        <td><label for="dock_books_search_visible_online_yes"> Yes</label></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="option" value="checkedVisibleNok" id="dock_books_visible_nok" /> </td>
                        <td><label for="dock_books_search_visible_online_no"> No</label></td>
```

Comment: Let this job done by Radios....!!

Comment: So...imagine that this has to be done with checkbox? what would be the solution then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For single selection from multiple options we use `Radio Buttons` not `CheckBoxes`.

You should use some thing like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="Yes" id="yes" /> 
<input type="radio" name="option" value="No" id="no" />
```

**But still** if you want to go the other way round, Just add the following script in your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(':checkbox.' + thisClass + ":not(#" + this.id + ")").removeAttr('checked');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wYDzj/2/) for above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you AlphaMale for the help!

Comment: Am Glad it Helped you. but may I ask why are you using checkboxes for this purpose..?

Comment: because I am using zend framework, and if I would change this script in a manner that it uses radio, I would literally be forced to change around hundred views, so it is easier for me to adjust to the views then to change it.. again..thx for your help.

Comment: why my answer unaccepted it gave me -15 rep would you tell me i know its because the votes up for @AlphaMale answer reached 9 but you asked for javascript not jquery so its up for the people i guess ?!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for radio buttons, not checkboxes.

Comment: you are right but if we have search result with lets say 13 record and i have a toolbar with 2 buttons edit and delete i would check as many i want to delete but for edit i can only check one record checkbox

Answer (score 2):

you got a point to use radio buttons any way here is the javascript solution
i used it in my project when there is search criteria and search result in data grid by
ajax having 13 records when i check one record it disables the rest

[code for javascript enable disable check boxes jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/cGcjj/)

```
<form  name="mainForm" method="GET">

   Visible online?


       <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="checkedVisibleOk" id="option"  onclick="changeCheckBox();"/>

 yes

        <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="checkedVisibleNok"     id="option" onclick="changeCheckBox();"/>

       no

</form>
<script>
var serNoChecked="";
function changeCheckBox() {
 try {

        var max = document.mainForm.option.length;
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (document.mainForm.option[i].checked == true) {
                count++;
                serNoChecked = i;
            }
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                if (document.mainForm.option[i].checked == false) {
                    document.mainForm.option[i].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (count == 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                document.mainForm.option[i].disabled = false;
            }
        }

        if (null == max) return false;
        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (count > 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Radio Button's, Give them the same name to group them and only allow 1 to be selected:

```
<td>
    <label for="dock_books_search_visible_online"> Visible online?</label>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="checkedVisibleOk" id="dock_books_visible_ok"  /> 
</td>
<td>
    <label for="dock_books_search_visible_online_yes"> Yes</label>
</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="option" value="checkedVisibleNok" id="dock_books_visible_nok" />
</td>
<td>
    <label for="dock_books_search_visible_online_no"> No</label>
</td>
```

[Check this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wYDzj/)

Answer (score 0):

Hi why are you using checkbox? Checkboxes are not for the functionality that you want. Radio buttons are exact what you want to use.

```
 <form>
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
 </form>
```

For further details look [here](http://www.activejump.com/m-7.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggle(chkBox, field) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        field[i].checked = false;
    }
    chkBox.checked = true;
}


<td>
    <INPUT type="checkbox" name="xyz" onClick="toggle(this,document.myform.xyz);" value="${incident.incidentID}">
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons and ensure that the name tag is consistent with all options and it'll automatically select just one w/o the need for additional code or JS.