# How to select only one checkbox from many checkboxes with Javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript

There are several checkboxes in html form.
And I need the user to be allowed to select only one checkbox.
For example: when clicked on the second checkbox, a message will be displayed that deactivates the previous checkbox.

Comment: Post your code attempts what you have done so far and what problems did you face

Comment: Aren't radio buttons supposed to do exactly what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only one selected checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724064/only-one-selected-checkbox)  OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518372/only-select-one-checkbox or other hundred  of examples here on SO.

Comment: @DanielGabzdyl  I have a problem with the radio button on the database side

Comment: database does not know what is radio button or what is checkboxes, it only knows values.

Comment: @DanielGabzdyl
        I use this code to send the values of the radio button and it works fine.
            But when it is deactivated, the values of the previous row must also change.
        $(function () {
            $('.radiobtn').change(function () {
                id = $(this).attr('data');
                statu = $(this).prop('checked');
                $.get("{{route('hero.status')}}", {id: id, statu: statu}, function (data, status) {
                });

            })
        })

Comment: That's just a radio button; https://jsfiddle.net/Lfm265rp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function message(){
    alert("You cant check more than 1 checkbox ")
}
document.querySelectorAll(".cgroup").forEach((chbx)=>{
    chbx.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
        if(!e.target.checked) return;
        var checkedbox = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".cgroup")).find(chbx=>chbx!=e.target&&chbx.checked)
        if(checkedbox){
            e.target.checked = false
            message()
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div>
      <input class="cgroup" type="checkbox">
      <input class="cgroup" type="checkbox">
      <input class="cgroup" type="checkbox">
      <input class="cgroup" type="checkbox">
    </div>
```

Comment: This code works fine.
But there is a problem. After displaying the warning, it deactivates the previous checkbox and selects the new checkbox.
I want the user to disable the previous checkbox.

Comment: @EricMat i edited it, now if this solves your problem please upvote and mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Radio button instead of a checkbox that will only allow a user to select one at a time. but for disabling you would have to write some javascript code after selection.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can disable/enable a checkbox via JavaScript using

```
document.querySelector('#your-selector').disabled=true
document.querySelector('#your-selector').disabled=false
```

You can check/uncheck a checkbox using

```
document.querySelector('#your-selector').checked=true
document.querySelector('#your-selector').checked=false
```

So you need to add a condition when to disable/enable or check/uncheck it based on your need.

That said as stated by others use of radio button is the suggested approach to your requirement.